# Android Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcast, alarm

I am working with alarm based app in my app I have set the alarm using the following code. If I create the alarm means its create but the alarm is not moving to the broadcast receiver. I have tried several time but its not working for me. Even though I have added the broadcast receiver in android manifest file correctly.

1.Setting Alarm class:

```
    public class Alertedit extends Activity {

   boolean AlarmEnabled;
   final static int RQS_1 = 1;
   TimePicker myTimePicker;

 private SQLiteConnectornew loginDataBaseAdapter;


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_alertaddlist);

     Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alerttime);

       bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openTimePickerDialog(false);
            }});}

            private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            Alertedit.this, 
            onTimeSetListener, 
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
            is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

        timePickerDialog.show();}

        OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
        = new OnTimeSetListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);
        }

        private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bt1.setText("" + targetCal.getTime());
            Log.d("set", "Alarm set");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Alertedit.this,  AlarmReciever.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alertedit.this, RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }};
```

2.Receiver class:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        /* Display an alert */
        Log.e("value", "how are you??");
        Toast.makeText(context, "How are you?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } 
     catch (Exception r) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You were supposed to do something"
              +" now but I can't retrieve what it was.",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("ALARM_RECEIVER", r.toString());
     }
  }
```

}

3.Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.contactlist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlist.Primemfrontpage"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlist.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlist.Registration"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlistnew.Alertedit"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.contactlistnew.AlarmReceiver">
    </receiver></application></manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should add intent-filter for your receiver, as below

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.contactlistnew.AlarmReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.alarm.demo.action" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: In my opinion, alarm sends broadcast only when time is up.

Comment: also, you can set the past time to alarm. If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately.

Answer (score 0):

from BroadcastReceiver must read the message from your Intent, something like that

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Extract data included in the Intent
        CharSequence intentData = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("message");   
        Toast.makeText(context, "Received the Intent's message: "+intentData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is working for me Please check once the time is to 2 minutes ahead from the current time.**

```
 public static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESTART_TIMER_TASK = 874378;

private void registerAlarm(Context applicationContext, int minute) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = getAlarmPendingIntent(applicationContext);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr1 = (AlarmManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmMgr1.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmMgr1.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        } else {
            alarmMgr1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }
    }
```

**And this is how you can create your pending intent**

```
private PendingIntent getAlarmPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intents = new Intent(context, ServiceRestartReceiver.class);
        intents.setAction(ServiceRestartReceiver.ACTION_TIMER_TASK);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE_RESTART_TIMER_TASK,
                intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

**This is how you cancel this alarm**

```
private void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = getAlarmPendingIntent(context);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr1 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr1.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
```

**Broadcast Receiver be like**

```
public class ServiceRestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_TIMER_TASK = "com.tracki.action.COUNTDOWN_TIMER";
    private static final String TAG = "ServiceRestartReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {

            if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
                switch (intent.getAction()) {

                    case ACTION_TIMER_TASK:
                        // DO your stuff here
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception occur inside ServiceRestartReceiver:onReceive(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.contactlist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlist.Primemfrontpage"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlist.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlist.Registration"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.contactlistnew.Alertedit"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
            android:name=".ServiceRestartReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
</application>
</manifest>
```